# C++ Learning how many numbers are repeated in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm learning C++. Something in my code isn't working but I don't understand what is the problem. I think is the incrementation of the stat array that counts how many numbers are repeated in T array... How can I fix it? Maybe is the syntax stat[elt]++ that is not correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int anneeSecu(int T[12][13], int j){
// here I join the 2 numbers of tab (they refer to the year of birth) and I add the number 20, because I know that they were born all after 2000
        int a = T[j][1];
        int b = T[j][2];

        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "20" << a << b;
        istringstream iss(oss.str());
        int ab;
        iss >> ab;
        int annee = ab;
        cout << annee << endl;
        return annee;
    }




int main(){
    int T[12][13]={ {1,1,2,0,2,3,7,1,9,8,2,0,5},
                    {2,1,3,0,5,8,9,9,0,8,1,0,2},
                    {2,1,6,0,8,1,9,2,6,5,4,8,7},
                    {2,1,5,0,6,5,6,3,4,6,0,6,7},
                    {1,1,5,0,6,5,6,3,4,6,0,7,5},
                    {2,1,5,0,2,5,6,3,4,6,0,6,7},
                    {2,1,5,0,6,2,9,1,4,7,1,6,3},
                    {2,1,4,0,6,2,2,1,4,7,1,6,3},
                    {2,1,4,0,9,3,5,1,4,7,1,6,3},
                    {1,1,1,1,2,5,6,1,7,5,0,0,7},
                    {1,1,1,0,9,5,6,1,7,5,1,0,7},
                    {2,1,4,1,0,3,5,1,4,7,0,2,2} };


    int stat[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int i=0;i<12;i++){
        int l=anneeSecu(T,i);
        **stat[l]++;**
    }

return 0;
}
```

Output and freeze of cmd

```
2012

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.764 s
Press any key to continue.
```

SOLUTION
The error was in stat[l]++ (because it takes numbers from 0 to 5 only...)
correction => stat[l-2011]++

Comment: Thanks for the adv. @Biffen ... Now can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with this piece of code:

```
int l=anneeSecu(T,i);
stat[l]++;
```

Because `anneeSecu` seams to return a number greather than the lenght of the array. `l` must be between 0 and 5, or your program will crash.

Comment: I don't understand. How can I write in order to have, for ex. for the year 2015 a code like this?


int l = 2015 (as a result of the anneeSecu fonction);
stat[2015]++; (that counts how many times 2015 is in the array)

Comment: Since you seem to know everything is between 2011 and 2016, you can just do a `stat[l-2011]` instead of `stat[l]`.
A cleaner solution would be to compute the smallest year in the array and offset everything by this value.

Comment: @Zouch ahhh!!! Now I understand... I thought that stat would act as if it was written like "stat[year] = counter of years.

I've always created array like this in Perl ... but never did in c++ and I don't know if it is possible to do and how. Thanks for the aid.

Comment: An alternative would be to use an [`std::map<int, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), but that's a bit overkill here.